# Installing error

Tags: 18.04, grub2, macbook-pro

I'm using an MacBook Pro 15 from 2019 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on an external drive from an USB stick so that later I could be able to boot Ubuntu on my Mac. At first I had problems with my keyboard and mouse not working, and I got around that by plugging external ones. After that i found that my internet wasn't working and I think that stops Ubuntu from fully installing ? Or Ubuntu can't find my wi-fi card :/ After I started the instalation process I got a "grub-efi-amd64-signed" package failed to install. Is this a driver problem and how can I get around it ?  I was also thinking about installing Ubuntu from a Windows machine on my external drive , and after that trying to boot it on my mac , is that going to work ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I suspect Ubuntu 18.04 (from 2018) will not give you much of a quality experience in a MacBook Pro 2019. Drivers may be too old for the hardware, etc.

You may find that 19.10 works better, or if I were you I'd try again in a month when 20.04 comes out, which may have better compatibility.

Apple locks down Macs pretty tightly, and they use a lot of proprietary parts for which open-source drivers are not available. They're not exactly open-source friendly. It often takes a couple of years for the open-source community to reverse-engineer drivers for macs to the point that you get a semi-decent user experience.

I have to say, the Linux UX in my MacBook Pro 2015 (already 5 years old), nice as the screen is, is nowhere close to what you can get with manufacturers that make Linux-ready laptops (System76, Lenovo, Dell...)